# react-redux - in the hooks documentation, why is a parameter of the selector put in a separate parametric selector when calling createSelector()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In the [`useSelector` hook examples of react-redux documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors), there's a code snippet:

```js
const selectNumOfTodosWithIsDoneValue = createSelector(
  state => state.todos,
  (_, isDone) => isDone,
  (todos, isDone) => todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone === isDone).length
)
```

As we can see, `isDone` is a parameter of `selectNumOfTodosWithIsDoneValue`. But why is it put in a separate parametric selector, i.e. `(_, isDone) => isDone`? Can I write it the following?

```js
const selectNumOfTodosWithIsDoneValue = createSelector(
  (state, isDone) => state.todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone === isDone),
  filteredTodos => filteredTodos.length
)
```

What's the difference between the 2 approaches?

Comment: To be honest, I'm really not happy with that particular example, and I'd like to come up with a different one.  There was a recent discussion on it at https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1515 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example will *always* cause a complete recalculation, because `filter()` *always* returns a new array reference.

While I'm not particularly happy with the current (first) example, it does memoize in that it will only recalculate the length if either `state.todos` or `isDone` have changed.

Comment: OK, I found the clues. According to [the API documentation of `createSelector`](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#createselectorinputselectors--inputselectors-resultfunc), "`createSelector` determines if **the value returned by an input-selector** has changed between calls using reference equality (`===`)." Actually I'm more fond of the **curried function pattern** posted in that [issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1515).